# Quick and easy way to make a button change a variable value?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I need the easiest most amateurish way of making some kind of button or link which, when pressed, changes a variable. So the page looks like this:

Value: Not-A

[Press here to change value to A](http://Ignore%20this)

So I want to make it so when you press the blue link, the only thing which happens is that Not-A changes to A. How do I do it?

Oh and I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<a var value=A href="#" onclick="var value = A">Press here to change value to A</a>
```

P.S: I googled this several times but I can't really figure out, I literally started learning javascript yesterday, sorry.

Comment: Sorry I tried to search it at google but couldn't figure it out :(

Comment: @Useraro Please follow some tutorials instead of trying random thing. They are a lot of misunderstanding in the code provided

Comment: @Useraro + Learn HTML before javascript

Comment: To add on to @Weedoze's comment, he means is's easier to learn HTML first, since you can use HTML without Javascript, but not (client-side) Javascript without HTML (at least not really).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go! The simplest solution I could think of, just like you asked for:

```html
<p id="toBeOrNotToBe">To Be</p>
<button type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('toBeOrNotToBe').innerHTML='Not To Be';">Change It!</button>
```

**EDIT:**

```js
var a="blahblahblah";
function showValueOfA(){
  document.getElementById("toBeOrNotToBe").innerHTML=a;
  console.log(a);
}
showValueOfA();
```

```html
<p id="toBeOrNotToBe"></p>
<button type="button" onClick="a='Yay I changed a variable!'; showValueOfA();">Change It!</button>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138402/discussion-on-answer-by-feathercrown-quick-and-easy-way-to-make-a-button-change).

Answer (score 0):

I also was looking into how to make a button do stuff in HTML and I came across this very good websited that walks you through how it works in great detail and it really helped me:
https://dev.to/bastionthedev/learning-with-clicker-games-part-1-html-1i4b

Comment: While this link may help the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.